# What was the first officially confirmed Easter Egg to occur in an MCU movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, easter-egg

What was the first Easter Egg to appear in a Marvel Cinematic Universe movie?

Looking for answers **that are confirmed by the writers/directors/etc.** to be Easter Eggs.

Comment: Well, it would be the first Easter Egg that appears in Iron Man, the first MCU movie. So I'm thinking. The Ten Rings group, which is a reference to the Mandarin?

Comment: what do you mean by easter egg? A goof reference to R2-D2 for example, or a setup in Iron Man 1 for a later movie?

Comment: What do you mean by exceptions? Are you saying you're interested in the MCU, *plus* Sony and Fox's movies based on Marvel characters? If not, then you can just say MCU.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I didn't want to include Sony/Fox movies as I thought it might become a really broad question.

Comment: @Shreedhar: sweet, then I think you just need to say “”Marvel Cinematic Universe”. Fox movies, and Sony movies (apart from the two Tom Holland Spiders-Mans), are [not part of the MCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first film in the MCU, *Iron Man*, has several Easter Eggs in it, such as Roxxon Corp, The Ten Rings and Rhodey's ringtone being the theme song for the 1966 *Iron Man* cartoon. These are all obviously "meant" Easter Eggs but I can't find them to be "officially confirmed" anywhere. However, the Nick Fury post-credits scene has been officially confirmed as an Easter Egg.

> **Favreau:** When we wanted to bring Nick Fury in, we thought it would be really fun to reach out to **Sam Jackson** because he was the person the character was based on in the Ultimates.
>
> **Feige:** Even though the notion of *The Avengers* came up at that Comic-Con—how could it not—the goal for 2008 was deliver two movies that we hope are profitable so we can do it again. It wasn’t sow the seeds of a big universe. That’s why we put Sam Jackson at the end, the very, very end of the credits, because we thought it would be fun. We thought it would be cool to have Sam come in and say, You’re part of a big universe; you just don’t know it yet.
>
> **Favreau:** For me it was just a fun Easter egg for the fans who would sit around until the credits were over. But at that point Kevin was definitely involved in all of that. Because specifically what Sam Jackson says about the Avengers initiative is a way to light that fuse. But for me it was very easy because it was just let’s have him pop in here and there and have him say that. But it was more about getting a reaction from the crowd. Kevin had other plans.
>
> <sub>[Vanity Fair, Marvel Looks Back at *Iron Man*—the Movie That Started It All](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/11/marvel-looks-back-at-iron-man-the-movie-that-started-it-all)</sub>

Comment: That sounds like a setup not an easter egg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setup_(storytelling)    The term easter egg originally referred to something hidden, like an inside joke, but now it seems to refer also to literary allusions.

Comment: @Martin At that moment in time they didn’t think they would be getting more films so they weren’t really setups. They were Easter Eggs to others things from the comics.